# Is the new Azure Web site durable? Can you use SQL Server CE in it?

Tags: azure, sql-server-ce

The new Web site instances for Azure appear to be VM's, without all of the server management stuff. I imply this because they're prices as VM's. So the question is, does that mean they have a durable file system? In other words, could you use SQL Server CE and keep stuff in app_data? I know you can't in a traditional Web role, so I'm looking for the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they are like a standard virtual machine as if you ran it in Hyper-V or VM-ware on your own Linux/Window server. The issue with that is that I cannot be shared between instance. So if you want to share the storage then use the Blob or other storage mechanisms. Just to be clear its the standard VHD disk that Hyper-V has.

[More Details](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/tutorials/virtual-machine-from-gallery/)

This is how you can store your data and also create a reusable method to not have to attach each time.

[Attaching a Disks to save](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/attach-a-disk/)

[Save your own Image](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/capture-an-image/)

Comment: Exactly what I was after. Understood about the non-shared storage, which is expected. It's a pretty solid win to toss up a prototype on the cheap with a file-based db though. Not a lot of info yet, or at least, the docs don't really answer the questions people will ask!

Comment: Yea its exactly like Amazon's EC2 for the VM (Just a side note).

Comment: You also might want to take a look at http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/capture-an-image/. This will save all the progroms. The VHD could technically be used across VMs, if I am reading everything correctly.